# Is this a false positive from Klocwork

Tags: c++, templates, memcpy, klocwork

*Background*

Consider the following code:

```
    template <typename T>
    void WriteData(const size_t &offset, const T &data)
    {
        if(sizeof(data) <= 8) //if size is 64bits or less, memcpy is not as efficient as a direct write
            *reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(_memView) + offset) = data;
       else
        {
            errno_t result = memcpy_s(reinterpret_cast<char*>(_memView) + offset, SHARED_BUFFER_SIZE - offset, &data, sizeof(data));
            if(result != 0)
                throw exception("Error writing data");
        }
    }
```

Assume that _memView is declared as a void pointer.
memcpy_s has NOT been redefined anywhere.

The function is only ever instantiated with the following types: char, int, HANDLE, unsigned int, long and unsigned long. Don't get bogged down in the other issues with this snippet, this is about klocwork.

This templated code is part of a class, and so this sits in a header file.

If i'm missing other relevent information just ask.

*The Issue*

After analysis with Klocwork, i'm getting the SV.BANNED.COPY warning: "Do not use unsafe buffer copy functions -- consider using a safe variant such as strcpy_s"

So am i doing something brain dead here with the way I'm calling memcpy_s, is memcpy_s considered insecure by Klocwork? Is Klocwork confused by the casting to char* and thinking i'm manipulating a C style string?

I'd like to understand what Klocwork is trying to tell me, even if it's just telling me it is a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

This function is all kinds of broken, according to standard C++.

- The `if` branches performs an unaligned write and violates strict aliasing.

Both branches will happily write off the end of your buffer.

- The `if` branch doesn't check the size at all.
- The `else` branch is subject to unsigned carry in the calculation of the buffer size argument.

`memcpy_s` isn't a cure-all.  Using `memcpy` and putting some thought into parameter validation will beat a blind call to `memcpy_s` every time.

Corrected version:

```
template <typename T>
void WriteData(const size_t &offset, const T &data)
{
    if (sizeof data > SHARED_BUFFER_SIZE)
        throw exception("Type cannot fit in shared buffer");
    if (offset > SHARED_BUFFER_SIZE - sizeof data)
        throw exception("Copy would overrun end of shared buffer");
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(_memView) + offset, &data, sizeof data);
}
```

To handle small copies efficiently, make sure that your compiler's treatment of `memcpy` as an intrinsic is enabled.

Comment: thanks for your input. I appreciate and understand there are other issues in the code that need looking at, but for this is more about what klockwork is trying to tell me. Using your fine example still results in warnings about using insecure functions (but more understandably so as i'm no longer using the secure memcpy_s)

Comment: Why the `reinterpret_cast`? Wouldn't `T*` be implictly converted to `void*`?

Comment: @sharptooth: The input to the `reinterpret_cast` isn't `T*`, and the offset is measured in bytes, so `char*` should be used for pointer arithmetic.